# jquery: not selector problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following snippet applies a #breadcrumb hash to each link once it's clicked. That works fine.

```
$('#main a').live('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#breadcrumbs");     
});
```

Now I want to make sure that happens just if a link does not already have a #hash in it. Otherwise what happens is I click a link and the outcome looks like this: `http://page.com/whatever#hash#breadcrumbs` I simply want to prevent that.

However the following code does not work. If I add the :not selector none of the links adds the #breadcrumb hash (with or without already existing #hash)

```
$('#main a:not([href*="#"]').live('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#breadcrumbs");     
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `a:not([href*=#])` (i.e. without double-quotes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:not` selector is missing a closing parenthesis. It should be:

```
$('#main a:not([href*="#"])').live('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "#breadcrumbs");     
});
```

Comment: you gotta be kidding me! i'm sorry-dumb. thank you!

Comment: 60 percent of the time it happens to the best of us, all the time! :)